# Почему по меньшей мере 4 способа форматированного вывода, почему это не соотносится с принципом из PEP?

Tags: python, format, pep

Цитата из [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

> There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.

Примеры разнообразного кода:

```
'hello, %s' % name
f'hello,  { name } '
'hello,  {  } '.format(name)
```

Comment: потому что после того как появился новый, лучший способ удалять старый нельзя

Comment: оставили бы один самый старый способ через оператор %, он не настолько хуже остальных, чтобы ради его замены попирать основные принципы языка

Comment: @Никита В старом способе вам нужно считать позиции вручную. Если у вас 10 переменных, то очень непросто сопоставить какой формат к какой из переменных относится.

Comment: старый способ _хуже_ остальных.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первый вариант уже морально устарел. Второй и третий дополняют друг друга. Например `f-string` не позволяет делать отложенную интерполяцию переменных. Т.е. если значение переменной на момент создания `f-string` вам неизвестно, тогда вам впоследствии придется воспользоваться [str.format()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

Пример:

```
s = f'hello,  {{name}}'
print(s)
name = 'Васисуалий'
print(s.format(name=name))
```

вывод:

```
hello,  {name}
hello,  Васисуалий
```

Я думаю основная причина в обратной совместимости. Наверняка вы бы не хотели исправлять тонны старого кода, если бы в новых версиях убрали возможность использовать `'hello, %s' % name`.

Answer (score 2):

Потому что язык развивается, появляются всё более лучшие, современные способы форматирования. Они, кстати, параллельно в разных языках появляются, создатели языков перенимают общие практики друг у друга.

Современный предпочтительный способ форматирования только один - это `f-строки`, всё остальное оставлено в основном для совместимости с написанным ранее кодом.